# Getting some data from input file - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, input

Suppose I upload from my desktop some image file (using some [jquery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)), before I send it to the server, I want to crop the image. How do I get the file url from the input file, (so to put the image in a window and crop it) and then how do I put in the input file data the new size of my image ? Because I read that for security reason this may not be possible

Comment: http://marqueetool.net/ - upload the image and then crop it

Comment: Use the JavaScript "File API" and the canvas. And google.

Comment: @Virus721 yes sure I did. I put `var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');var reader = new FileReader(); reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);` but I got nothing

Comment: @mplungjan yes I know about this plugin, but what I want is to get the input file url so I can put the image in a window and then crop it

Comment: You need to set the src property before trying to read, else what are you reading ?

Comment: @Virus721 ok perhaps I am missing something, but we are right `file api` is html5 based, how do I handle it for old browsers ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, JavaScript isn't (wasn't) made to access local files from a browser. But there are maybe some libraries that can do it. Ask google ;-)

Comment: You can maybe have a look at java applets.

Answer (score 0):

I did this some time ago. I used a plugin called JCrop to crop my images. It works really great.

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

A quick example:

Let's suppose we have this image our markup:

```
<img src="flowers.jpg" id="target" />
```

To convert this into a Jcrop widget, insert the following script:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#target').Jcrop();
    });
</script>
```

This script will do the following:

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/tutorial1.html

Comment: yes I know about this plugin, but what I want is to get the input file url so I can put the image in a window and then crop it

Comment: You can just redirect your upload to a new page and crop it there. I don't get why you want to do it that way.

Comment: You must wait for the image to be loaded, unless the plugin handles it.